# Swift: TableView scroll to position

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Maybe this is the wrong way of doing this so please show me the correct way if its wrong. I have a tableview on a scrollview. Most cells have a TextField which onclick it shows the keyboard. The problem I am having is that cells at the bottom of the scroll view end up getting stuck behind the keyboard.

```
// I build the tableView
self.shippingTableView = UITableView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 5, self.view.frame.width, CGFloat(tableViewHeight)))
self.shippingTableView.delegate = self
self.shippingTableView.dataSource = self
self.shippingTableView.scrollEnabled = true
self.scrollView.addSubview(self.shippingTableView)

// Create some delegate methods
// I know i'm not reusing cells yet but will update later.
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = UITableViewCell()
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.None

    let textField = UITextField(frame: CGRectMake(10, 0, cell.frame.width, cell.frame.height))
    textField.delegate = self
    cell.contentView.addSubview(textField)
    return cell
}
```

Now from the above code I have the view on the page and if i select a item, the keyboard shows but with the cell behind. I created my delegate method and tried the following. I added a print line to this method so I know its getting called.

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {
    let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forItem: textField.tag, inSection: 0)

    // I tried each of the following separatly, but nothing moves.
    self.shippingTableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, atScrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.Top, animated: true)
    self.shippingTableView.scrollToNearestSelectedRowAtScrollPosition(UITableViewScrollPosition.Middle, animated: true)
}
```

I guessed the problem was because I had a tableView within a scrollView but I tried changing this to just a standard view and had the same problem.

Surely the correct answer is not to scroll manually?

Comment: The easiest way to achieve this is (if possible), make your controller a subclass of `UITableViewController` as this has built-in keyboard avoiding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First don't add `UITableView` in `UIScrollView`. Download [TPKeyboardAvoiding](https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPKeyboardAvoiding) make TPKeyboardAvoidingTableView as super class of tableview. And you don't have to worry about scroll tableview manually, TPKeyboard will handle automatically.

Comment: Thanks, that is a great library. No fiddling about needed.